# How can I make a two line nav bar? using html and css only

Tags: html, css

sample photo is like this :

[image]

my code as of now is this:

```css
.topnav{
 background-color: #0624c5;
 overflow: hidden;
 padding: 30px;
}

.topnav a{
 color: #ffffff;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #ffffff;
 padding: 15px 16px;
 font-size: 15px;
 font-family: Raleway Medium;
 border-right: 1px solid #0120b8;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  color: #ff0004;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div>
  <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
   <a href="#" style="color: #ff0004;">Home</a>
   <a href="#">About Us</a>
   <a href="#"><span>Companionship & Personal Care Services</span></a>
   <a href="#">Alzheimer’s & Parkinson’s Services</a>
   <a href="#">Our Caregivers</a>
   
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

I hope someone can answer me . It will be a huge help in my activity.. thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this just use `display: inline-block` with `max-width`. Check updated snippet below

```css
.topnav{
  background-color: #0624c5;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 30px;
}

.topnav a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: Raleway Medium;
  border-right: 1px solid #0120b8;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  color: #ff0004;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <a href="#" style="color: #ff0004;">Home</a>
    <a href="#">About Us</a>
    <a href="#"><span>Companionship & Personal Care Services</span></a>
    <a href="#">Alzheimer’s & Parkinson’s Services</a>
    <a href="#">Our Caregivers</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`display: table` and `display: table-cell` properties is the solution for your issue. You can make change to these 2 css selector to achieve your desired result.

```
.topnav{
    background-color: #0624c5;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 30px;
  display: table;
}

.topnav a{
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 15px 16px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: Raleway Medium;
    border-right: 1px solid #0120b8;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```